# How can you hide comment dates in DISQUS?

Tags: disqus

Is there any hack to hide comment dates in DISQUS?

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to do this. The comments are loaded via an iFrame and you can not modify the content of the iframe because of cross-origin policies. If enough people want this feature request to the Disqus team to add it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can.  Set all the class "time-ago" elements to style.display='none';

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('time-ago');
for (var i=0, i<elements.length, i++){
  elements[i].style.display='none';
}
```

I did find in comments.php on line 110 this code:

'date':            ,
You could try commenting out that line (add // in front of 'date':) and see what happens.

Or you could try changing:

```
get_comment_date('m/d/Y h:i A'))
```

To:

```
get_comment_date(''))
```

### UPDATE

I would never use Discus because I find it disgusting.  I did not look in to how it is distributed and whether you have access to the Discus javascript.  I would assume if you host the source on your own site you could add the original javascript into the Discus source.

If you want to put the javascript fix in your javascript residing outside the iFrame you must then make a reference to the iFrame id.  Then use that reference to get the time-ago class elements

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("dsq-app1");
var discus= iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var elements = discus.getElementsByClassName('time-ago');
for (var i=0, i<elements.length, i++){
      elements[i].style.display='none';
}
```

The Discuss source must be located on your server.  If not you may have to setup a proxy on your server to deliver the iFrame contents.

Comment: Can you please tell me where I can find that code? (using wordpress)

Comment: I just wrote it, here is the only place it exists.  What else do you need to know?  I am assuming you know basic javaScript.

Comment: I am wondering where is the source code I need to change? The disqus file... (I'm actually a beginner hacking my way through code)

Comment: This is independent from Disqus.  If you have the source code the solution would be different.  I have never worked with Disqus I just went to a site that uses it and Inspected the time element.  If you have the source search through all the source looking for "time-ago".

Comment: I managed to change it using "Inspect element" in Chrome. But I need it changed in the source code, and that's where I get stuck.

Can't find "time-ago".

Comment: Here are all the DISQUS files: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m7r93howcfb1gau/disqus-comment-system.zip?dl=0

Comment: Does not work. The answer is based on the assumption that you have cross-origin support.

Comment: @Rick I am not needing to do a cross domain request.  I am only changing what is displayed on the Browser window, which I have access rights to.  If it's in my DOM it belongs to me. The "time-ago"  elements are in my DOM.  All I do is change the time-ago elements[i].style.display='none'.

Comment: Exactly @Misunderstood any element inside an iframe from a cross domain can't be changed from the parent domain.